# Is there any equivalence for cumtrapz in mathematica

Tags: numerical-integration

I saw another question raised by someone related to this. However I do not quite follow up.

Please just to clarify, have a look at below problem:

http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/124120?sortMsg=Flat

I have an array like

```
x = Array[# &, 101, {0, 1}];
```

Also I have a function

```
inside_int[x_] = 
  1/2  (1 - ((h + (1 - b)*θ))/(h + (x - 
           b) θ - κ Sin[π x]))^2;
```

I need to integrate this function with respect to x and plot it over x. (my h and theta are numerical values say h = 0.5 theta = 0.1).

Answer (score 2):

You did not fully parameterize your function, but let's try this:

```
insideInt = With[{h = 1/2, θ = 1/10, κ = 1, b = 1/2},
  Function[x, 
  (1/2) (1 - (h + (1 - b)*θ)/(h+(x-b) θ - κ Sin[π x]))^2]
  ]
Plot[insideInt[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

The resulting image shows singularities in the function:

[image: some singularities]

So we could proceed as you seem to want to:

```
nTraps = 100;  (* the number of trapezoids *)
xs = Subdivide[nTraps];  (* points in the domain *)
ys = insideInt /@ xs;  (* corresponding function values *)
trapHeights = Partition[ys, 2, 1] ;(* 100 pairs of function values *)
trapAreas = Total /@ trapHeights/(2*nTraps);  (* areas of 100 traps *)
accumulatedTrapAreas = Accumulate[trapAreas];
ListLinePlot[Transpose@{Most[xs], accumulatedTrapAreas}]
```

But now if you change `nTraps` to say 1000, you will get a radically different result.

Comment: Thanks so much @Alan (and Feyre for editiing). I need to study this code. I was wondering if there are singularities in my inside_int function, how can I integrate this function then?

Comment: Also in inside_int , the square covers the fraction as I posted in the question. Yours is slightly different from mine @Alan. However, it does not change that there  are singularities.

Comment: @Meva I did not change the value of the function you posted, other than to specify the needed parameter values.  It appears that this function is not  integrable over [0,1], with those parameter values.

Comment: @Meva Fyi: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work